# Elastic search single huge document vs multiple small documents

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

Following is the behaviour:
1. each record is generated for an order.
2. each record has some common data that will be same across all the records for an order.
3. The records for an order may range from 1k to 500k

There are two ways:
Either merge all the records for an order and index in ES or index per record documents in ES.

What must be the approach ?

Comment: Do you need to update those documents? Or they will be the same as added initially? what kind of search scenarios you have for them?

Comment: no updates to the records/smaller documents. Search is to get all the records for an order with a given key, where key is present in each record.